# vb.net SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text) send slow simulation write

Tags: vb.net

vb.net  SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)      send slow simulation write

```
Process.Start("notepad")

SendKeys.Send(TextBox1.Text)
```

I write what is in TextBox1, to write very slowly
I want to simulate writing unite man

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of EXACTLY what you want.  Are you saying that you want to send one character at a time with a delay in between?  If so then say that.  Programming is about being precise. Code can't be vague so descriptions of what code has to do cannot be vague.

Comment: Yes. send one character at a time with a delay in between .... sorry I do not know English

Comment: So, how do you usually do something multiple times with a delay in between?  Using a `Timer`.  What you do after each delay doesn't change that.

Comment: I want to send is in textbox
For example textbox1= Hello
I want to send  "H" expects 1 second "e" expects 1 second "l" expects 1 second "l" expects 1 second "o"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SimulateWriting() ' Call me to start
    With Timer ' Initialize the timer
        .BeginInit()
        .AutoReset = True
        .Enabled = True
        .InitializeLifetimeService()
        .EndInit()
        .Start() ' Start typing now
    End With
    Process.Start("notepad") ' Start Notepad
End Sub
WithEvents Timer As New Timers.Timer(1000) ' The timer with its interval set to 1 second (aka 1000 milliseconds)
Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer.Elapsed ' When one second is elapsed
    Static Counter As Integer = 0 ' Stores the character position to sendkey
    SendKeys.Send(Textbox1.Text(Counter)) ' Sends the key
    Counter += 1 ' Update the counter
    If Counter >= Textbox1.Text.Length Then ' All characters are sent
        Counter = 0 ' Reset the counter
        Timer.Stop() ' No need to send keys again
    End If
End Sub
```